# With python socketserver how can I pass a variable to the constructor of the handler class

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver

I would like to pass my database connection to the EchoHandler class, however I can't figure out how to do that or access the EchoHandler class at all.

```
class EchoHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print self.client_address, 'connected'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "10.0.0.5", user = "user", passwd = "pass", db = "database")

    SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = 1

    server = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('10.0.0.6', 4242), EchoHandler)

    print "Server listening on localhost:4242..."
    try:
        server.allow_reuse_address
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nbailing..."
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately, there really isn't an easy way to access the handlers directly from outside the server.

You have two options to get the information to the EchoHandler instances:

1. Store the connection as a property of the server (add `server.conn = conn` before calling `server_forever()`) and then access that property in EchoHandler.handler through `self.server.conn`.
2. You can overwrite the server's `finish_request` and assign the value there (you would have to pass it to the constructor of EchoHandler and overwrite EchoHandler.__init__). That is a ***far messier*** solution and it pretty much requires you to store the connection on the server anyway.

My optionon of your best bet:

```
class EchoHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # I have no idea why you would print this but this is an example
        print( self.server.conn );
        print self.client_address, 'connected'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = 1

    server = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('10.0.0.6', 4242), EchoHandler)
    server.conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "10.0.0.5", 
                     user = "user", passwd = "pass", db = "database")
    # continue as normal
```

Answer (score 11):

Mark T has the following to say on the python list archive

In the handler class, self.server refers to the server object, so subclass
the server and override **init** to take any additional server parameters
and store them as instance variables.

```
import SocketServer

class MyServer(SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, arg1, arg2):
        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, 
                                                 server_address, 
                                                 RequestHandlerClass)
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2


class MyHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print self.server.arg1
        print self.server.arg2
```

Comment: Why not do `super().__init__(...)` instead in `MyServer.__init__`?

Comment: Classes in the SocketServer modules are "old-style" classes. The super constructor has to be called this way. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527921/python-inheriting-from-old-style-classes

Comment: @ShivangiSingh probably best to post a question.  Then we can see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, that I believe more pythonic, is to do the following:

```
class EchoHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def __call__(self, request, client_address, server):
    h = EchoHandler(self.a, self.b)
    SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.__init__(h, request, client_address, server)
```

You can now give an **instance** of your handler to the TCPServer:

```
SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('10.0.0.6', 4242), EchoHandler("aaa", "bbb"))
```

The TCPServer normally creates a new instance of **EchoHandler** per request but in this case, the **__call__** method will be called instead of the constructor (it is already an instance.)

In the **call** method, I explicitly make a copy of the current EchoHandler and pass it to the super constructor to conform to the original logic of "one handler instance per request".

It is worth having a look at the SocketServer module to understand what happens here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py

Answer (score 1):

I was currently solving same problem, but I used slightly different solution, I feel it's slightly nicer and more general (inspired by @aramaki).

In the `EchoHandler`  you just need to overwrite `__init__` and specify custom `Creator` method.

```
class EchoHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # super().__init__() must be called at the end
        # because it's immediately calling handle method
        super().__init__(request, client_address, server)

    @classmethod
    def Creator(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        def _HandlerCreator(request, client_address, server):
            cls(request, client_address, server, *args, **kwargs)
        return _HandlerCreator
```

Then you can just call the `Creator` method and pass anything you need.

```
SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('10.0.0.6', 4242), EchoHandler.Creator(0, "foo"))
```

Main benefit is, that this way you are not creating any more instances than necessary and you are extending the class in more manageable way - you don't need to change the `Creator` method ever again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't use `ForkingServer` to share variables because Copy-on-Write happens when a process tries to modify a shared variable.
Change it to `ThreadingServer` and you'll be able to share global variables.