# how to use super command python

Tags: python, super

I'm having problem using super command

```
class s:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a

    def show(self):
        print self.a


class t:
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b=b

    def show2(self):
        print self.b


class w(s):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super(w,self).__init__()
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

    def show3(self):
        super(w,self).show()
        print self.b
        print self.c
```

whenever i make an object it gives the following error

```
x=w(1,2,3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
x=w(1,2,3)
File "C:\Users\GURSAHEJ\Desktop\k.py", line 13, in __init__
super(w,self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`super` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) will Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type so  when you want to use it you need to pass the parent name to it,and since here your `w` class inherit from `s` you might want to pass `s` to `super`:

```
class w(s):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super(s,self).__init__()
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
```

Also don't forget to pass the [`object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) to your parent class to make it a [new style class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) :

```
class s(object):
        def __init__(self,a):
            self.a=a
        def show(self):
            print self.a
```

Read about *new style and classic classes* it in python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `super` on an [old-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)

In Python 2.x (>= 2.2), there are two type of classes. Old style classes and new-style classes. In python 3.x, old-style classes are removed and all classes are new-style class.

Python's *build-in function* `super` works properly on new-style classes.

Simply, new-style classes extends `object` while old style classes not.

### Old Sytle Class

```
class s:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
```

### New Style Class

```
class s(object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a=a
```

So, your classes which is not inherited from another class should be inherited from `object` to be a new style class.

You can either use *new-style* or use old-skool inheritance `__init__`

```
class w(s):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        s.__init__(self, a)
```

This is an example of [old-style solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527921/python-inheriting-from-old-style-classes), but I do not flag this question as a duplicate because new-style class usage is encouraged and you should avoid using old-style classes.