# Python inheritance old style type in a new style class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm using the `csv.DictWriter` class, and I want to inherit it:

```
class MyObj(csv.Dictwriter):
    ...
```

But this type is an old-style object. Can `MyObj` be a new-style class but still inherit from `csv.DictWriter`?

Comment: `class MyObj(csv.DictWriter, object)`? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11527921/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you only have to inherit from `object`, too:

```
class MyObj(object, csv.DictWriter):
    def __init__(self, f, *args, **kw):
        csv.DictWriter.__init__(self, f, *args, **kw)
```

Comment: And then how the__init__ methood will look?

Comment: @NI6: as with any normal class, see answer.

Comment: Hm, this is the opposite order that https://stackoverflow.com/a/11528159/321973 suggests, since your way makes `object`'s methods override `csv.Dictwriter`'s ones. And the very point of using a newstyle class is _not_ explicitly calling a specific parent class' methods but rather being able to use `super()`, isn't it?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: `object` and `DictWriter` have no methods in common, so the order is not important. And regarding `super` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066315/why-is-super-broken-in-python-2-x

Comment: @Daniel That is actually what I'd consider a good example for _wrong_ inheritance. As long as no multiple inheritance is used, we're splitting hairs here, but say we subclass `class GrandChild(MyObj, AnotherCSVThing)`, you either have to explicitly call _both_ parents' constructors or let `super` handle it, in which case `MyObj` _not_ using `super` will break the whole MRO mechanism... So TL;DR your answer is not incorrect, but it _may_ lead to difficult-to-debug behaviour in the future...

Comment: ...and yes, `DictWriter` does not share any methods with `object`, but in general, even an old-style class might implement e.g. `__str__`, which in this case would be overridden by `object`'s more generic `<MyObj object at 0x0001240105015618616>`

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel correctly [states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34842062/321973), you need to mixin `object`. However, one major point of using new-style classes is also using `super`, thus you should use

```
class MyObj(csv.DictWriter, object):
    def __init__(self, csvfile, mycustomargs, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyOobj, self).__init__(csvfile, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11528159/321973), `object` should be the last parent, otherwise `object`'s default methods such as `__str__` and `__repr__` will override the other parent's implementation, which is certainly not what you wanted...