# send a variable to a TCPHandler in python

Tags: python, tcp, socketserver

I'm confused as to how to send a variable to a TCPHandler using SocketServer.TCPServer in python..

```
HOST, PORT = hosts[0], args.port
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), METCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Which calls:

```
class METCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):           
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        r = MExpressHandler(self.data, False)
```

But I want to pass a debug boolean to MExpressHandler.. so

```
HOST, PORT = hosts[0], args.port
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), METCPHandler(debug))
server.serve_forever()
```

Fails. Whats the correct way of doing this? Do I have to recreate a whole TCPHandler over-ridding `__init__`?

Comment: Look at this, it's a duplication to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875599/with-python-socketserver-how-can-i-pass-a-variable-to-the-constructor-of-the-han

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trust your instincts, the correct way *is* indeed to subclass TCPServer and override the `__init__` method, but Python makes this very easy!

```
import SocketServer

class DebugTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True, debug=True):
        self.debug = debug
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True)

class DebugMETCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # self.server is an instance of the DebugTCPServer
        DEBUG = self.server.debug
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        if DEBUG:
            print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
        r = MExpressHandler(self.data, False)


server = DebugTCPServer((HOST, PORT), DebugMETCPHandler, debug=True)
```

or since we specified `debug=True` as the default:

```
server = DebugTCPServer((HOST, PORT), DebugMETCPHandler)
```

Comment: thanks! I'm getting a NameError: name 'TCPServer' is not defined. Do I have to define the whole thing somehow? Sorry for being dim..

Comment: Make sure you import it "from SocketServer import TCPServer" or reference it like "SocketServer.TCPServer"

Comment: The prob is on the `class DebugMETCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):`
line. Should that be something different..?
`class DebugMETCPHandler(DebugTCPServer.BaseRequestHandler):`
I wondered but no joy

Comment: I didn't notice TCPServer is an old-style class, which means we can't call super, instead you call the init methods of the base class directly

Comment: thanks John_GG. Still causing the same error though.. `class DebugTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):` no matter how the SocketServer is imported (e.g. from SocketServer import *). (To be more precise 'NameError: name 'SocketServer' is not defined')

Comment: To use my code, you must import the SocketServer module with this command `import SocketServer`. Then any time you use a class from that module, you must reference it by prepending the SocketServer module name, ie, `SocketServer.TCPServer` or  `SocketServer.UDPServer`. The modules that we subclassed, are defined in your module's namespace so we reference them with just their class name, e.g., `DebugMETCPHandler`, or `DebugTCPServer`

Comment: Ahh I was being an idiot as to be expected. Thanks John. A hero.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `SocketServer` was renamed to `socketserver` for PEP 8 compliance.  See [socketserver docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socketserver.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875599/) already, it is possible to do it without sub-classing the TCPServer. It is in fact more concise and generic.

You can give parameters to your handler this way:

```
class METCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
  def __init__(self, debug):
    self.debug = debug

  def __call__(self, request, client_address, server):
    h = METCPHandler(self.debug)
    SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.__init__(h, request, client_address, server)
```

You can now give an **instance** of your handler to the TCPServer:

```
SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), METCPHandler(True))
```

The TCPServer normally creates a new instance of **METCPHandler** per request but in this case, the **__call__** method will be called instead of the constructor (it is already an instance.)

In the **call** method, I explicitly make a copy of the current METCPHandler and pass it to the super constructor to conform to the original logic of "one handler instance per request".

It is worth having a look at the SocketServer module to understand what happens here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/SocketServer.py