# Python socketserver.BaseRequestHandler must raise an event on file received

Tags: python, multithreading, socketserver

Being a newbie in python and server programming, I am trying to wrap my head around the socketserver and it's threading mixin.

So far i have created a working server that handles ping-requests and can receive multiple files - one file per thread.

Thing is that I want the TCHandler to raise an event with the name of the received file, for further processing by another thread.
I can, for the life of me, not wrap my head around how to implement an event in the TCPHandler.

My thought is that I need to insert the event into the TCPHandler when instantiating it, however it is not I that instantiates the handler class, but the ThreadedTCPServer class?

Anyone got any ideas? - Or am I just way, way, way off track here, and need to try a different approach all together?

I could of course just implement the further processing in the TCPHandler, however since i want to pre-process sime images before introducing them to a classifier, I'd rather have the preprocessing and classification running from a queue, and not in the TCPHandler thread.

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you only pass a BaseRequestHandler subclass to the TCPServer, because it will create a new request handler instance per request. So if you want to give *something* to the request handler instances, a simple way would be to make it a class attribute. That way it will be shared among the instances. More or less:

```
class TCPHandler(BaseRequestHandler):

    event_obj = ...

    def handle(self):
        ...
        event_obj.signal(received_file)
        ...
```

Comment: Ah yes, that would be an option, however how would you register eventListeners in the eventHandler, if the eventHandler is instantiated in the TCPHandler class?

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually solves most of my issues.

[send a variable to a TCPHandler in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889241/send-a-variable-to-a-tcphandler-in-python)

Further testing is needed, but it looks good so far